# Weakref and __slots__

Tags: python, weak-references

Consider the following code:

```
from weakref import ref

class Klass(object):
    # __slots__ = ['foo']
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'bar'

k = Klass()
r = ref(k)
```

it works but when I uncomment the `__slots__` it breaks with `TypeError: "cannot create weak reference to 'Klass' object"` under Python 2.6.

Please, does anyone know if this is an inherent limitation of Python and `__slots__` or if it is a bug? How to work-around it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Without a `__weakref__` variable for each instance, classes defining `__slots__` do not support weak references to its instances. If weak reference support is needed, then add `__weakref__` to the sequence of strings in the `__slots__` declaration.

From the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots).

If you add `__weakref__` to `__slots__`, your code will work:

```
>>> from weakref import ref
>>>
>>> class Klass(object):
>>>     __slots__ = ['foo', '__weakref__']
>>>     def __init__(self):
>>>         self.foo = 'bar'
>>> k = Klass()
>>> k
 => <__main__.Klass object at ...>
>>> r = ref(k)
>>> r
 => <weakref at ...; to 'Klass' at ...>
```

Comment: That's a great answer, but I couldn't google it. To improve it's indexing I quote the error message that occurs when facing this exact issue creating reference to object  with __slots__: The message is `TypeError: cannot create weak reference to given object`. It occurs in python 2.7, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, but what interesting - does not in pypy and pypy3.

Answer (score 9):

You have to add `__weakref__` to the list of slots. It's one of the [`__slots__` quirks](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots). Prior to 2.3, even this didn't work, but luckily your version isn't that old.